# Proper usage of RxSwift to chain requests, flatMap or something else?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

First of all, I'm new to rxswift so I guess the answer is obvious however at the moment I can't find solution by myself.

I have two functions:

```
func downloadAllTasks() -> Observable<[Task]>
func getTaskDetails(taskId: Int64) -> Observable<TaskDetails>
```

First one is downloading the list of Task objects using network request, second one downloading task details for sepcific task (using it's id)

What I want of achieve is to download all tasks and then for each task I want to download its details and subscribe for the event fired when all tasks details are ready.

So I guess I should subscribe somehow to Observable<[TaskDetails]> but I don't know how to do it.

```
        downloadAllTasks()
        .flatMap{
            ... // flatMap? something else?
        }
        .subscribe(
            onNext: { details in
                print("tasks details: \(details.map{$0.name})")
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

//EDIT

Thanks to Silvan Mosberger answer I'm much closer to the solution. One problem left. Now I have something like this:

```
    downloadAllTasks()
        .flatMap{ Observable.from($0) } 
        .map{ $0.id }
        .flatMap{ [unowned self] id in
            self.getTaskDetails(taskId: id).catchError{ error in
                print("$$$ Error downloading task \(id)")
                return .empty()
            }
        }
        .do(onNext: { _ in
            print(" $$$ single task details downloaded")
        } )
        .toArray()
        .debug("$$$ task details array debug", trimOutput: false)
        .subscribe({ _ in
            print("$$$ all tasks downloaded")
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

The output is

```
$$$ task details array debug -> subscribed
$$$ single task details downloaded
$$$ single task details downloaded
$$$ single task details downloaded
```

There are 3 tasks available so as you can se all of them are downloaded properly however for some reason the result of toArray() - (`Observable<[TaskDetails]>`) doesn't produce "onNext" once all task details are ready.

// Edit once more

Ok, I'm adding simplified version of functions providing observables, maybe it will help something

```
func downloadAllTasks() -> Observable<Task> {
    return Observable.create { observer in

            //... network request to download tasks
            //...

            for task in tasks {
                observer.onNext(task)
            }
            observer.onCompleted()

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}


func getTaskDetails(id: Int64) -> Observable< TaskDetails >  {
    return Observable.create { observer in

        //... network request to download task details
            //...

        observer.onNext(taskDetails)

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With RxSwift you want to use `Observable`s whenever possible, therefore I recommend you to refactor the `downloadAllTasks` method to return an `Observable<Task>`. This should be fairly trivial by just looping through the elements instead of emitting the array directly:

```
// In downloadAllTasks() -> Observable<Task>
for task in receivedTasks {
    observable.onNext(task)
}
```

If this is not possible for whatever reason, there is also an operator for that in RxSwift:

```
// Converts downloadAllTasks() -> Observable<[Task]> to Observable<Task>
downloadAllTasks().flatMap{ Observable.from($0) }
```

In the following code I will be using the refactored `downloadAllTasks() -> Observable<Task>` method because it's the cleaner approach.

You can then `map` your tasks to get their id (assuming your `Task` type has the `id: Int64` property) and `flatMap` with the `downloadAllTasks` function to get an `Observable<TaskDetails>`:

```
let details : Observable<TaskDetails> = downloadAllTasks()
    .map{ $0.id }
    .flatMap(getTaskDetails)
```

Then you can use the `toArray()` operator to gather the whole sequence and emit an event containing all elements in an array:

```
let allDetails : Observable<[TaskDetails]> = details.toArray()
```

In short, without type annotations and sharing the tasks (so you won't download them only once):

```
let tasks = downloadAllTasks().share()

let allDetails = tasks
    .map{ $0.id }
    .flatMap(getTaskDetails)
    .toArray()
```

EDIT: Note that this Observable will error when any of the detail downloads encounters an error. I'm not exactly sure what's the best way to prevent this, but this does work:

```
let allDetails = tasks
    .map{ $0.id }
    .flatMap{ id in
        getTaskDetails(id: id).catchError{ error in
            print("Error downloading task \(id)")
            return .empty()
        }
    }
    .toArray()
```

EDIT2: It's not gonna work if your `getTaskDetails` returns an observable that never completes. Here is a simple reference implementation of `getTaskDetails` (with `String` instead of `TaskDetails`), using [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com):

```
func getTaskDetails(id: Int64) -> Observable<String> {
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/\(id)")!
    return Observable.create{ observer in
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                observer.onError(error)
            } else if let data = data, let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                observer.onNext(result)
                observer.onCompleted()
            } else {
                observer.onError("Couldn't get data")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        return Disposables.create{
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean explanation, thanks a lot. And it's almost working as I want. Almost, beacause I have problem with last part - toArray(). Without this part the subscriber is notified properly about tasks details download events. With toArray I would expect that i get notified in subscriber's onNext when all task details are downloaded, but onNext is not called at all. Do you see what can be a problem?

Comment: @Wujo When a single task detail download encounters an error, the final `Observable` will error. You should be able to check that with a `.debug()` before the `.toArray()`. I edited my answer for if you want it to complete even though there was an error

Comment: The problem is not in error during getTaskDetails, all tasks details are downloaded properly. I edited my original post trying to point it out more clearly.

Comment: @Wujo Are you sure you didn't forget the `observable.onComplete()` in the `Observable`-generating code? Could you maybe share the (simplified) implementation of those? Because I tested it and it worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code as it's more complicated with some additional dependencies etc. But you are right, I'm not calling onComplete anywhere, but where should I call it? From downloadAllTasks?

Comment: I've added edit with simplified version of observable creation functions

Comment: @Wujo Edited my answer again, you didn't implement `getTaskDetails` correctly

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I have to complete each separate getTaskDetails observable as each of them is separate "stream" of events (with just only one event fired) . Adding onComplete in getTaskDetails do the job. Thanks for your time, I appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

There's a far simpler solution than the accepted answer:

```
downloadAllTasks()
    .flatMap { tasks in
        Observable.zip(tasks.map { getTaskDetails(taskId: $0.id) })
    }
```

There is no need to break the array into a bunch of individual Observables and then try to cram them all back into an array later. The `zip` operator will take an array of Observables and convert them into a single Observable that contains an array.

Note that in the above case, if any one `getTaskDetails` call fails the entire stream fails, whereas in the accepted answer if a getTaskDetails fails the Task in question will just silently get removed from the array. I'm not sure that either of those solutions is good.

Better, I think is to pass on the Task object so the calling code knows it exists even if it doesn't have all the details. Something like this:

```
struct TaskGroup {
    let task: Task
    let details: TaskDetails?
}

func example() -> Observable<[TaskGroup]> {
    downloadAllTasks()
        .flatMap { tasks in
            Observable.zip(tasks.map { task in
                getTaskDetails(taskId: task.id)
                    .map { TaskGroup(task: task, details: $0) }
                    .catch { _ in Observable.just(TaskGroup(task: task, details: nil)) }
            })
        }
}
```

The difference here is what is inside the `flatMap`. If `getTaskDetails` succeeds, a TaskGroup will be created with both the task and its details. If an error is emitted, the error isn't ignored like in the accepted answer, instead it will emit a TaskGroup that contains a task but nil for the details.